# How can I created new custom Calendar widget in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
    function get_calendar($initial = true, $echo = true) {
    global $wpdb, $m, $monthnum, $year, $wp_locale, $posts;

    $cache = array();
    $key = md5( $m . $monthnum . $year );
    if ( $cache = wp_cache_get( 'get_calendar', 'calendar' ) ) {
        if ( is_array($cache) && isset( $cache[ $key ] ) ) {
            if ( $echo ) {
                echo apply_filters( 'get_calendar',  $cache[$key] );
                return;
            } else {
                return apply_filters( 'get_calendar',  $cache[$key] );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( !is_array($cache) )
        $cache = array();

    // Quick check. If we have no posts at all, abort!
    if ( !$posts ) {
        $gotsome = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT 1 as test FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 1");
        if ( !$gotsome ) {
            $cache[ $key ] = '';
            wp_cache_set( 'get_calendar', $cache, 'calendar' );
            return;
        }
    }

    if ( isset($_GET['w']) )
        $w = ''.intval($_GET['w']);

    // week_begins = 0 stands for Sunday
    $week_begins = intval(get_option('start_of_week'));

    // Let's figure out when we are
    if ( !empty($monthnum) && !empty($year) ) {
        $thismonth = ''.zeroise(intval($monthnum), 2);
        $thisyear = ''.intval($year);
    } elseif ( !empty($w) ) {
        // We need to get the month from MySQL
        $thisyear = ''.intval(substr($m, 0, 4));
        $d = (($w - 1) * 7) + 6; //it seems MySQL's weeks disagree with PHP's
        $thismonth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('{$thisyear}0101', INTERVAL $d DAY) ), '%m')");
    } elseif ( !empty($m) ) {
        $thisyear = ''.intval(substr($m, 0, 4));
        if ( strlen($m) < 6 )
                $thismonth = '01';
        else
                $thismonth = ''.zeroise(intval(substr($m, 4, 2)), 2);
    } else {
        $thisyear = gmdate('Y', current_time('timestamp'));
        $thismonth = gmdate('m', current_time('timestamp'));
    }

    $unixmonth = mktime(0, 0 , 0, $thismonth, 1, $thisyear);
    $last_day = date('t', $unixmonth);

    // Get the next and previous month and year with at least one post
    $previous = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_date < '$thisyear-$thismonth-01'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY post_date DESC
            LIMIT 1");
    $next = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_date > '$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY post_date ASC
            LIMIT 1");

    /* translators: Calendar caption: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year */
    $calendar_caption = _x('%1$s %2$s', 'calendar caption');
    $calendar_output = '<div align="center"><table width="300px" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #eee;"><tr><td width="150px" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><table id="wp-calendar">
    <caption>' . sprintf($calendar_caption, $wp_locale->get_month($thismonth), date('Y', $unixmonth)) . '</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>';

    $myweek = array();

    for ( $wdcount=0; $wdcount<=6; $wdcount++ ) {
        $myweek[] = $wp_locale->get_weekday(($wdcount+$week_begins)%7);
    }

    foreach ( $myweek as $wd ) {
        $day_name = (true == $initial) ? $wp_locale->get_weekday_initial($wd) : $wp_locale->get_weekday_abbrev($wd);
        $wd = esc_attr($wd);
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t<th scope=\"col\" title=\"$wd\">$day_name</th>";
    }

    $calendar_output .= '
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>';

    if ( $previous ) {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev"><a href="' . get_month_link($previous->year, $previous->month) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($previous->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $previous->month, 1, $previous->year)))) . '">&laquo; ' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($previous->month)) . '</a></td>';
    } else {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';
    }

    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';

    if ( $next ) {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next"><a href="' . get_month_link($next->year, $next->month) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($next->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $next->month, 1, $next->year))) ) . '">' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($next->month)) . ' &raquo;</a></td>';
    } else {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';
    }

    $calendar_output .= '
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
    <tr>';

    // Get days with posts
    $dayswithposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(post_date)
        FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_date >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_date <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59'", ARRAY_N);
    if ( $dayswithposts ) {
        foreach ( (array) $dayswithposts as $daywith ) {
            $daywithpost[] = $daywith[0];
        }
    } else {
        $daywithpost = array();
    }

    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'camino') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'safari') !== false)
        $ak_title_separator = "\n";
    else
        $ak_title_separator = ', ';

    $ak_titles_for_day = array();
    $ak_post_titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, DAYOFMONTH(post_date) as dom "
        ."FROM $wpdb->posts "
        ."WHERE post_date >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00' "
        ."AND post_date <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59' "
        ."AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'"
    );
    if ( $ak_post_titles ) {
        foreach ( (array) $ak_post_titles as $ak_post_title ) {

                $post_title = esc_attr( apply_filters( 'the_title', $ak_post_title->post_title, $ak_post_title->ID ) );

                if ( empty($ak_titles_for_day['day_'.$ak_post_title->dom]) )
                    $ak_titles_for_day['day_'.$ak_post_title->dom] = '';
                if ( empty($ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"]) ) // first one
                    $ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"] = $post_title;
                else
                    $ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"] .= $ak_title_separator . $post_title;
        }
    }

    // See how much we should pad in the beginning
    $pad = calendar_week_mod(date('w', $unixmonth)-$week_begins);
    if ( 0 != $pad )
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="'. esc_attr($pad) .'" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';

    $daysinmonth = intval(date('t', $unixmonth));
    for ( $day = 1; $day <= $daysinmonth; ++$day ) {
        if ( isset($newrow) && $newrow )
            $calendar_output .= "\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t";
        $newrow = false;

        if ( $day == gmdate('j', current_time('timestamp')) && $thismonth == gmdate('m', current_time('timestamp')) && $thisyear == gmdate('Y', current_time('timestamp')) )
            $calendar_output .= '<td id="today">';
        else
            $calendar_output .= '<td>';

        if ( in_array($day, $daywithpost) ) // any posts today?
                $calendar_output .= '<a href="' . get_day_link( $thisyear, $thismonth, $day ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $ak_titles_for_day[ $day ] ) . "\">$day</a>";
        else
            $calendar_output .= $day;
        $calendar_output .= '</td>';

        if ( 6 == calendar_week_mod(date('w', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $thismonth, $day, $thisyear))-$week_begins) )
            $newrow = true;
    }

    $pad = 7 - calendar_week_mod(date('w', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $thismonth, $day, $thisyear))-$week_begins);
    if ( $pad != 0 && $pad != 7 )
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td class="pad" colspan="'. esc_attr($pad) .'">&nbsp;</td>';

    $calendar_output .= "\n\t</tr>\n\t</tbody></td></table></td><td style='text-align: right; vertical-align: top; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;'><td align='left' valign='top'><embed src='http://img.mikufan.pl/mikuclock.swf' quality='high' bgcolor='#ffffff' name='mikuclock' allowscriptaccess='sameDomain' allowfullscreen='false' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' align='middle' height='180' width='150'></td></td></tr></table></div>";

    $cache[ $key ] = $calendar_output;
    wp_cache_set( 'get_calendar', $cache, 'calendar' );

    if ( $echo )
        echo apply_filters( 'get_calendar',  $calendar_output );
    else
        return apply_filters( 'get_calendar',  $calendar_output );

}
```

This is modified calendar code in WordPress from file general-template.php. If I change oryginal calendar code for this code, then I have my modiied calendar. But I have new instalation of WordPress, than I don't modiffy oryginal filles, but I want my calendar. So, how I can create new widget plugin with this code? I created new simply widget plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My New simple widget #1
Plugin URI: http://mikufan.pl/
Description: This is my new simple widget plugin...
Author: Idolw Szutrab
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: http://idolwszutrab7.tumblr.com/
*/

function sampleHelloWorld() 
{
  echo "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
}

function widget_myHelloWorld($args) {
  extract($args);
  echo $before_widget;
  echo $before_title;?>My Widget Title<?php echo $after_title;
  sampleHelloWorld();
  echo $after_widget;
}

function myHelloWorld_init()
{
  register_sidebar_widget(__('Hello World'), 'widget_myHelloWorld');     
}
add_action("plugins_loaded", "myHelloWorld_init");
?>
```

But when I paste code o my callendar to this code, then plugin dosen't work. So, how I can paste of my calendar code to plugin code? In short... I want to use my callendar, but I don't want modiffy oryginals wordpress file :/ How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the class/function for the calendar from `default_widgets.php` in wp-includes folder and also copy the `get_calendar()` function from `general_template.php` into your `functions.php` file for your theme.

You will need to rename the class and rename `get_calendar()` to something unique.
Once you do that you will find a widget in your admin that is controlled by this new function. You can name it what you want and change the html in the `get_calendar()` function if desired.

Comment: I copy get_calendar() from general_template to my funtions.php and also copy class calendar from default_widgets.php also to my functions.php but I don't know what now. Of course I renamed "get_calendar" to "get_mikuCalendar" and class name "WP_Widget_Calendar" to "WP_Widget_mikuCalendar".